# What's causing these triangle/banding artifacts on my baked shadow texture, and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: workflow, texture-baking, shadows, artifacts

I'm baking a 1024x1024 Shadow map for a character and I'm getting a lot of triangular artifacts around the eyes and banding around the upper skull and jaw.

[image: shadowMap for head and hands]

I don't think I've encountered this before - does anybody know what's causing this or how I can get rid of it?

EDIT - IMAGES IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS
[image]
Separated the maps a little more in response to comments, but this doesn't seem to affect the texture bake outcome.

[image]

Comment: Check Face orientation (Normals) ...

Comment: Also check smoothing of high and low poly object, and make sure auto smoothing is turned off for both models as well

Comment: @vklidu - Normals seem normals, have added the .blend in case you can see any issue there.

Comment: @James - Autosmoothing is turned off. Have added the .blend above in case you can see any issue with it.

Comment: Your UV map is heavily overlapping ...

Comment: @vklidu - Could you clarify on this? Are you referring to the head and neck margins being quite close together? (something I'm going to change now) I'm not sure how this would relate to the issues that I'm having...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black triangles on hands are defects of overlapping faces of your UVmap ... like now some of them shares same pixels. So you have to change those parts manually or use Unwrap > Smart.

[image]

The "triangles" on smooth surface are the same you can see when you change shading to **Flat** ... **Smooth** shading is not calculated in bake.

[image]

I'm not a master so I don't knot if this is a limit or error, but you can avoid that by increasing *Subdivision modifier* temporarily for baking. Like here with Render Level 6.

[image]

**Edit:** It seems to me it is (surprisingly for me) **Terminator** issue. When I go to *Properties Editor > Object Properties tab > Shading > Shadow Terminator Offset* and set **0.25** it seems to be gone without Subdiv modifier increasing.

Comment: Deleted my comments. I did try the Terminator Offset https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oecXkpAoq9U but didn't seem to get great results. Are you using any subdivision at this point? What are your settings, Terminator Offset aside? Thanks for the efforts!

Comment: Just Subdiv modifier at 2 and Terminator as written 0.25 ... Since I started to use a different lightninghan yours, I will check that again tomorrow. Issue doesn't look like a Terminator, but seemed to me it worked for bake.